# How to expand a sequence (var-args) into distinct items

Tags: clojure

I want to send var-args of a function to a macro, still as var-args.
Here is my code:

```
(defmacro test-macro
 [& args]
 `(println (str "count=" ~(count args) "; args=" ~@args)))

(defn test-fn-calling-macro
 [& args]
 (test-macro args))
```

The output of `(test-macro "a" "b" "c")` is what I want: `count=3; args=abc`

The output of `(test-fn-calling-macro "a" "b" "c")` is : `count=1; args=("a" "b" "c")` because args is sent as a single argument to the macro. How can I expand this args in my function in order to call the macro with the 3 arguments?

I guess I'm just missing a simple core function but I'm not able to find it. Thanks

---

**EDIT 2** - My "real" code, shown in EDIT section below is not a valid situation to use this technique.

As pointed out by @Brian, the macro `xml-to-cass` can be replaced with a function like this:

```
(defn xml-to-cass
  [zipper table key attr & path]
  (doseq [v (apply zf/xml-> zipper path)] (cass/set-attr! table key attr v)))
```

---

**EDIT - the following section goes beyond my original question but any insight is welcome**

The code above is just the most simple I could come with to pinpoint my problem. My real code deals with clj-cassandra and zip-filter. It may also look over-engineering but it's just a toy project and I'm trying to learn the language at the same time.

I want to parse some XML found on mlb.com and insert values found into a cassandra database. Here is my code and the thinking behind it.

**Step 1 - Function which works fine but contains code duplication**

```
(ns stats.importer
  (:require
    [clojure.xml :as xml]
    [clojure.zip :as zip]
    [clojure.contrib.zip-filter.xml :as zf]
    [cassandra.client :as cass]))

(def root-url "http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/year_2010/month_05/day_01/")

(def games-table (cass/mk-cf-spec "localhost" 9160 "mlb-stats" "games"))

(defn import-game-xml-1
  "Import the content of xml into cassandra"
  [game-dir]
  (let [url (str root-url game-dir "game.xml")
        zipper (zip/xml-zip (xml/parse url))
        game-id (.substring game-dir 4 (- (.length game-dir) 1))]
    (doseq [v (zf/xml-> zipper (zf/attr :type))] (cass/set-attr! games-table game-id :type v))
    (doseq [v (zf/xml-> zipper (zf/attr :local_game_time))] (cass/set-attr! games-table game-id :local_game_time v))
    (doseq [v (zf/xml-> zipper :team [(zf/attr= :type "home")] (zf/attr :name_full))] (cass/set-attr! games-table game-id :home_team v))))
```

The parameter to `import-game-xml-1` can be for example `"gid_2010_05_01_colmlb_sfnmlb_1/"`. I remove the "gid_" and the trailing slash to make it the key of the ColumnFamily games in my database.

I found that the 3 `doseq` were a lot of duplication (and there should be more than 3 in the final version). So code templating using a macro seemed appropriate here (correct me if I'm wrong).

**Step 2 - Introducing a macro for code templating (still works)**

```
(defmacro xml-to-cass
  [zipper table key attr & path]
  `(doseq [v# (zf/xml-> ~zipper ~@path)] (cass/set-attr! ~table ~key ~attr v#)))

(defn import-game-xml-2
  "Import the content of xml into cassandra"
  [game-dir]
  (let [url (str root-url game-dir "game.xml")
        zipper (zip/xml-zip (xml/parse url))
        game-id (.substring game-dir 4 (- (.length game-dir) 1))]
    (xml-to-cass zipper games-table game-id :type (zf/attr :type))
    (xml-to-cass zipper games-table game-id :local_game_time (zf/attr :local_game_time))
    (xml-to-cass zipper games-table game-id :home_team :team [(zf/attr= :type "home")] (zf/attr :name_full))))
```

I believe that's an improvement but I still see some duplication in always reusing the same 3 parameters in my calls to `xml-to-cass`. That's were I introduced an intermediate function to take care of those.

**Step 3 - Adding a function to call the macro (the problem is here)**

```
(defn import-game-xml-3
  "Import the content of xml into cassandra"
  [game-dir]
  (let [url (str root-url game-dir "game.xml")
        zipper (zip/xml-zip (xml/parse url))
        game-id (.substring game-dir 4 (- (.length game-dir) 1))
        save-game-attr (fn[key path] (xml-to-cass zipper games-table game-id key path))]
    (save-game-attr :type (zf/attr :type)) ; works well because path has only one element
    (save-game-attr :local_game_time (zf/attr :local_game_time))
    (save-game-attr :home :team [(zf/attr= :type "home"] (zf/attr :name_full))))) ; FIXME this final line doesn't work
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a some simple code which may be illuminating.

Macros are about code generation. If you want that to happen at runtime, for some reason, then you have to build and evaluate the code at runtime. This can be a powerful technique.

```
(defmacro test-macro
 [& args]
 `(println (str "count=" ~(count args) "; args=" ~@args)))

(defn test-fn-calling-macro
 [& args]
 (test-macro args))

(defn test-fn-expanding-macro-at-runtime
  [& args]
  (eval (cons `test-macro args)))

(defmacro test-macro-expanding-macro-at-compile-time
  [& args]
  (cons `test-macro args))

;; using the splicing notation

(defmacro test-macro-expanding-macro-at-compile-time-2
  [& args]
  `(test-macro ~@args))

(defn test-fn-expanding-macro-at-runtime-2
  [& args]
  (eval `(test-macro ~@args)))



(test-macro "a" "b" "c") ;; count=3; args=abc nil
(test-fn-calling-macro "a" "b" "c") ;; count=1; args=("a" "b" "c") nil

(test-fn-expanding-macro-at-runtime "a" "b" "c") ; count=3; args=abc nil
(test-macro-expanding-macro-at-compile-time "a" "b" "c") ; count=3; args=abc nil
(test-macro-expanding-macro-at-compile-time-2 "a" "b" "c") ; count=3; args=abc nil
(test-fn-expanding-macro-at-runtime "a" "b" "c") ; count=3; args=abc nil
```

If contemplation of the above doesn't prove enlightening, might I suggest a couple of my own blog articles?

In this one I go through macros from scratch, and how clojure's work in particular:

http://www.learningclojure.com/2010/09/clojure-macro-tutorial-part-i-getting.html

And in this one I show why run-time code generation might be useful:

http://www.learningclojure.com/2010/09/clojure-faster-than-machine-code.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to write that. I kind of feel enlightened now. I will go through your blog posts too for sure. Too bad I didn't learn Lisp when I was a kid rather than a stubborn adult. I have hard time getting my brain around it. But so far it's worth the pain. I won't give up and hopefully grasp the thinking.

Comment: Sorry to answer in kata! There are subtleties, and one has to play for a while before understanding. Don't worry about your brain. I didn't touch a repl until I was about 35. It takes about a year. One day you'll try to write something in a language with syntax and suddenly realise that you feel trapped by it.

Comment: The way to really grok it is to go through SICP and do all the exercises. http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/ In fact it hardly mentions macros, but about the time where you write a scheme interpreter in scheme, you'll understand exactly what's going on in the evaluator, and at that point macros are a trivial corollary. Even if your aim is to program in clojure or some other complex lisp, this is a good thing to do, because scheme is so simple that you can see the ideas. A bit like learning Java first if what you really want to do is C++.

Answer (score 2):

The typical way to use a collection as individual arguments to a function is to use `(apply function my-list-o-args)`

```
(defn test-not-a-macro [& args]
    (print args))

(defn calls-the-not-a-macro [& args]
   (apply test-not-a-macro args))
```

though you wont be able to use apply because test-macro is a macro. to solve this problem you will need to wrap test macro in a function call so you can apply on it.

```
(defmacro test-macro [& args]
    `(println ~@args))

(defn calls-test-macro [& args]
   (eval (concat '(test-macro) (args)))) ;you almost never need eval.

(defn calls-calls-test-macro [& args]
   (calls-test-macro args))
```

This is actually a really good example of one of the ways macros are hard to compose. (some would say they cant be composed cleanly, though i think thats an exageration)

Comment: ps: i'm not at my REPL so if this is broken please edit (or comment and i'll fix when i get home)

Comment: Thanks. I tried this code but I get a `ClassCastException: clojure.lang.ArraySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn`. Any idea why? I really though there would be a straight forward answer to my question but it looks surprisingly complex. I edited my question to provide all the details about my "real" code. Maybe it could help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Macros are not magic. They are a mechanism to convert code at compile-time to equivalent code; they are not used at run-time. The pain you are feeling is because you are trying to do something you should not be trying to do.

I don't know the library in question, but if `cass/set-attr!` is a function, I see no reason why the macro you defined has to be a macro; it could be a function instead. You can do what you want to do if you can rewrite your macro as a function instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Brian. You're totally right. I was able to make it work as a function. It seems I've not yet acquired enough skills to play with macros. But I'm hesitant about accepting your answer. Couldn't there be a theoretical case where someone would really need to "forward" var-args from function to macro? @Arthur's answer with the `eval` function may be more appropriate for those people.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements aren't clear. I don't see why a macro is necessary here for `test-macro`, unless you're trying to print the *unevaluated forms* supplied to your macro.

These functions provide your expected results, but that's because your sample data was *self-evaluating*.

```
(defn test-args
  [& args]
  (println (format "count=%d; args=%s"
                    (count args)
                    (apply str args))))
```

or

```
(defn test-args
  [& args]
  (print (format "count=%d; args=" (count args)))
  (doseq [a args]
    (pr a))
  (newline))
```

You can imagine other variations to get to the same result.

Try calling that function with something that doesn't evaluate to itself, and note the result:

```
(test-args (+ 1 2) (+ 3 4))
```

Were you looking to see the arguments printed as "37" or "(+ 1 2)(+ 3 4)"?

If you were instead trying to learn about macros and their expansion in general, as opposed to solving this particular problem, please tune your question to probe further.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My code with the println was completely artificial and as simple as possible to pinpoint the problem. I didn't want to bother people with irrelevant code. But since you asked, I edited my question and provided all the details on why I thought I needed a macro. I can't be more specific ;o)